# Get the Description of a Service?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

**How may I get the description of a Windows Service like below?**

[image]

I tried by using the Windows Registry, but the majority of Services appear to not have a description, or the description value is stored in a dll - so this seems to be the wrong approach.

Example:

**Windows Time Service** (W32Time), the description in the registry is shown as

> @%SystemRoot%\system32\w32time.dll,-201

Yet the actual description as seen in Services.msc is:

> Maintains date and time synchronization on all clients and servers in
>   the network. If this service is stopped, date and time synchronization
>   will be unavailable. If this service is disabled, any services that
>   explicitly depend on it will fail to start.

-

I have been searching on the MSDN website and came across this:

[SERVICE_DESCRIPTION structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685156%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> **lpDescription**
>
> The description of the service. If this member is NULL, the
>   description remains unchanged. If this value is an empty string (""),
>   the current description is deleted.
>
> The service description must not exceed the size of a registry value
>   of type REG_SZ.
>
> This member can specify a localized string using the following format:
>
> @[path]dllname,-strID
>
> The string with identifier strID is loaded from dllname; the path is
>   optional. For more information, see [RegLoadMUIString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724890%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)....
>
> -
>
> **pszOutBuf [out, optional]**
>
> A pointer to a buffer that receives the string.
>
> Strings of the following form receive special handling:
>
> @[path]\dllname,-strID
>
> The string with identifier strID is loaded from dllname; the path is
>   optional. If the pszDirectory parameter is not NULL, the directory is
>   prepended to the path specified in the registry data. Note that
>   dllname can contain environment variables to be expanded.

Which I think would suggest why viewing the Registry showed the W32Time description as @%SystemRoot%\system32\w32time.dll,-201

If I understand correctly I need to read the dll name in memory and retrieve the strID where the Service description is stored?

This is all confusing for me, I would be grateful if someone could help.

All I need is to get the description of a Service, it surely cannot be as complicated as this can it?

Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean thanks, are you trying to be sarcastic or something? I asked a question I wasn't sure on, I needed some help and assistance. I read on MSDN and still didn't understand it. If i didn't put down what I researched it would look to many that I was just looking for someone else to do the work for me. That is not what I want, I just wanted some advice on how to do something which I thought this website was for. No need to be sarcastic about it though.

Comment: actually i wasnt [trying to be] sarcastic. Anyway, you accepted the answer where JEDI contributor(s) did work for you. This clearly indicates.

Comment: Windows has the capability to use resources to store localized data (event log messages use the same mechanism, for example). Service description can be localized the same way, and it became even more important since Windows language can be switched so applications can't perform localization tasks at setup only. You would need to read the DLL resources using the correct locale for the system you're running on. But if you use the Service Manager API, Windows will do it for you - and that's the "published" way. Internal storage of those data may change, APIs are more stable.

Comment: @user539484 no it doesn't clearly indicate that at all. As it appears to already have been done (ie the Jedi libraries which I did not know about), there is no reason for me to attempt to rewrite it all. If anything, I can study and see how the code works from the units of the Jedi libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In all versions of Delphi, the the [JEDI JCL](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/index.php?title=JEDI_Code_Library) contains everything you need to get friendly descriptions of services, and anything else to do with the Service Control APIs.

THe class TJclSCManager in the unit JclSvcCtrl.pas contains a property Services, which includes name and description of each service registered, and lets you also do things like start, stop, enable, and disable services too.

**Update**: The other answer here from ldsandon points out that the Delphi RTL apparently includes this already in XE2, in the unit WinSvc.  See answer below about  QueryServiceConfig2. Thanks ldsandon for pointing this fact out.

Comment: If you don't want a dependency on Jedi you can call win32 service control manager API.

Comment: It is also possible to extract just a few units from jedi into a folder and avoid having to rewrite the API wrappers.

Comment: You don't really need to "rewrite the API wrappers". Delphi can call the API directly, all needed types and constants are already declared in the RTL AFAIK. If the needs are simple enough, it's just a matter of thee API calls. If the aim is to write a service management application that's another matter.

Comment: Oi. Nobody understands english.  The code that calls the API directly is not zero lines of code, or one. There are record type declarations, constants, etc, involved. All that stuff is there in the JEDI JCL, just cut and paste, instead of retyping it, that's all I'm sayin'

Comment: That's a good idea to cut down on the units. I've just noticed how many units link to other units, which link to other units, which link to other units etc etc. There seems to be a lot of units used in the Jedi libraries!

Comment: @Blobby That's always my gripe with JEDI. It's pretty much trivial to call the Win32 API to extract the info you need.

Comment: @WarrenP: WinSvc units declares what you need but QueryServiceConfig2 (as of D2010, don't know about XE or XE2). Anyway that function takes "simple" parameters, thereby importing it is one line of code.
I'm not a native English speaker, but a "wrapper" looks something more than importing a function. Writing a service management class looks more like a wrapper :)
Jedi is an excellent library (I use it myself), but when tasks are simple enough I may decide to skip it to avoid a lot of dependencies.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes it does seem extreme in some cases using those Jedi libraries if all you need is a few functions. It does what I need but I think I will research some more, particularly QueryServiceConfig2 which is mentioned in the MSDN. At least then I could try and write my own smaller functions.

Comment: @ldsandon, I think this is one of those cases where I will also skip the Jedi libraries and try and research/write my own smaller functions.

Comment: @ldsandon XE does not declare it. XE2 does. I call it from one of my D6 apps simply by declaring it in my code. Not hard to do at all.

Answer (score 4):

Call [QueryServiceConfig2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684935%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (you will find also a C example there).

Whatever you need to do with services should be done through the [Service Manager API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Registry data should be treated as "private" to the OS.

Answer (score 2):

Using **[WMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation)** is another way to use the Windows API directly, for example with the help of the (free) API code generator

**[WMI Delphi Code Creator](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/wmi-delphi-code-creator/)**

> The WMI Delphi Code Creator tool allows you to generate Object Pascal
>   and C++ code to access the WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation)
>   classes, events and methods.

Comment: Just beware that WMI goes through COM because it is designed to be used by tools that cannot call the Windows API directly (script languages, etc.). It could be easier to use (although somewhat "heavier"), while the API usually give better control and better error codes when something goes wrong.

Comment: Great information and thanks for the caution, I have been reading about WMI on the Wikipedia site you linked too there is certainly plenty of information to digest!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Unicode?  The remarks for the [RegLoadMUIString function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724890%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) say that only the Unicode version is supported.

> The RegLoadMUIString function is supported only for Unicode. Although
>   both Unicode (W) and ANSI (A) versions of this function are declared,
>   the RegLoadMUIStringA function returns ERROR_CALL_NOT_IMPLEMENTED.
>   Applications should explicitly call RegLoadMUIStringW or specify
>   Unicode as the character set in platform invoke (PInvoke) calls.

Have you tried calling `RegLoadMUIStringW` directly?

Answer (score 0):

You also can check [the **GLibWMI** library](http://neftali.clubdelphi.com/?p=589). Free (and source included) library for work with WMI. Include a component named **TServiceInfo**. 
Also is included a demo for work wirh services.

With this component you can access at Win32_Service Class; You can check [the properties and structure here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Regards